# WordPress: wp_validate_auth_cookie failing due to HMAC mismatch

Tags: php, wordpress

I am migrating a WordPress install onto a new server and have become stuck on a strange bug, likely caused by me setting something incorrectly.

This site has a custom (I think) admin panel located in /admin which seems to be made from a combination of joomla and wordpress include files. The part that is not functioning correctly is the wp_validate_auth_cookie function, which is failing at this stage:

```
    $key = wp_hash($username . $pass_frag . '|' . $expiration, $scheme);
    $hash = hash_hmac('md5', $username . '|' . $expiration, $key);

    if ( $hmac != $hash ) {
            do_action('auth_cookie_bad_hash', $cookie_elements);
            return false;
    }
```

In order to log in I had to manually reset a couple of passwords by generating an MD5 hash and writing that into the wp_users table, which may have something to do with it - I looked back at the same row later and the hash had changed from my regular MD5 hash into a WordPress format hash. The site is also a MultiSite install and while I can log into wp-admin fine, visiting ..com/admin is always causing me to log out and return to the login page even when already logged in.

Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you compared your function to the one default on wordpress? http://wpseek.com/wp_validate_auth_cookie/

Comment: I have - there was a small difference but I normalised this and the problem still persists